# "математика" or "математику"

Tags: винительный-падеж

I want to write the sentence "At the university I go to the first lecture, mathematics." Is "В университете я иду на первую лекцию, математика." a right translation or does "математика", like "лекцию", have to be in accusative (математику)?

Comment: Nominative case is appropriate only with the use of quotation marks, like "В университете я иду на первую лекцию - "математика""

Comment: i would better write "по математике"

Comment: I think you have to add a preposition or pronoun.

Answer (score 4):

Accusative is more suitable in this case.

> В университете я иду на первую лекцию, математику.
>   В университете я иду на первую лекцию - математику.
>   В университете я иду на первую лекцию, на математику.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, it could be better Russian to say

> Я иду на первую лекцию в университете,

or

> Я иду в университете на первую лекцию,

and for the Nominative case add

> это математика.

Without **это** you would have to put the clarifying word in the same case as the object it clarifies. Here it is Accusative.